# Jenkins Groovy - using modified data from readYaml to write back into yml file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml

I am using Jenkins readYaml to read the data as follows:

```
data = readYaml file: "test.yml"
//modify
data.info = "b"
```

I want to write this modified data back to test.yml in Jenkins. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

test.yml:

```
data:
  info: change me
  aaa: bbb
  ddd: ccc
```

pipeline script:

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions
import static org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK

node {
    def yaml = readYaml file: "test.yml"
    yaml.data.info = 'hello world!'
    writeFile file:"test.yml", text:yamlToString(yaml)
}

@NonCPS
String yamlToString(Object data){
    def opts = new DumperOptions()
    opts.setDefaultFlowStyle(BLOCK)
    return new Yaml(opts).dump(data)
}
```

final test.yml:

```
data:
  info: hello world!
  aaa: bbb
  ddd: ccc
```

Answer (score 12):

There is a writeYaml nowadays, see [pipeline-utility-steps-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md)

```
mydata = readYaml file: "test.yml"

// modify
mydata.info = "b"
writeYaml file: 'newtest.yaml', data: mydata
```

Comment: @tung for a Dockerized Jenkins server or Jenkins Runner, just add the script using the following command: `RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh pipeline-utility-steps`

Comment: According to the docs, `writeYaml` only allows you to write a `Map` back to a file, but does not allow you to convert it into a `String`. Hence @dagget's `yamlToString` function.

Comment: @IanD.Rossi where does the OP mention "converting anything to String"? The only thing I see that could be pointed out about this answer is not writing to the same file it read from.