# Merging two yaml files in a Jenkins Groovy pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml

In my Jenkins pipeline, I've got a yaml file that I need to apply to multiple environments, and separate environment specific yaml files that I'd like to inject or merge into the default file and write as a new file.

I've looked at readYaml and writeYaml here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/  But I'm not finding a good way of merging multiple files.

A simple example of what I'd like to achieve is here:

```
# config.yaml
config: 
   num_instances: 3
   instance_size: large
```

```
# dev-overrides.yaml
config:
    instance_size: small
```

```
# dev-config.yaml (desired output after merging dev-overrides.yaml in config.yaml)
config
    num_instances: 3
    instance_size: small
```

Comment: just search how to merge maps in groovy. possibly you want deep(nested) merge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Groovy - using modified data from readYaml to write back into yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694656/jenkins-groovy-using-modified-data-from-readyaml-to-write-back-into-yml-file)

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins implementation of `readYaml` uses [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) as processor and supports YAML 1.1. You could possibly use the merge operator to accomplish your goal. But the merge operator has been removed in YAML 1.2. Thus I would not advise using this feature even it's currently available.

I would instead merge the objects with some Groovy code like this:

```
Map merge(Map... maps) {
    Map result = [:]
    maps.each { map ->
        map.each { k, v ->
            result[k] = result[k] instanceof Map ? merge(result[k], v) : v
        }
    }

    result
}


def config = readYaml text: """
config: 
   num_instances: 3
   instance_size: large
"""

def configOverrides = readYaml text: """
config:
    instance_size: small
"""

// Showcasing what the above code does:
println "merge(config, configOverrides): " + merge(config, configOverrides)
// => [config:[num_instances:3, instance_size:small]]
println "merge(configOverrides, config): " + merge(configOverrides, config)
// => [config:[instance_size:large, num_instances:3]]

// Write to file
writeYaml file: 'dev-config.yaml', data: merge(config, configOverrides)
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27476077/1549149