# How to read and overwrite a value in a specific path yaml file using Groovy used in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want modify yaml file by using Jenkins pipeline:

1. A repo is cloned/checked-out using Groovy script mentioned in Jenkins pipeline on a Linux (ubuntu) server
2. I need to navigate to a specific folder, open the test.yaml file and overwrite the branch parameter under `yyy` module

Example of my pipeline:

```
checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: "${params.xxx}"]], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[
                      $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
                      relativeTargetDir: 'test']], 
        gitTool: 'Default', 
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[
                    credentialsId: 'github_access',
                    url: 'https://github.com/test-xxxx.git']]
```

File location example in Linux server:
`cd ./test/ex/ex1/test.yaml`

*test.yaml*

```yaml
xxx:
    branch: main
    provision: xxxxx
    submodule_branch: ''
    url: https://github.com/xxx.git

yyy:
    branch: main
    provision: yyy
    url: https://github.com/yyy.git

zzzz:
    branch: main
    url: https://github.com/zzz.git
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Groovy - using modified data from readYaml to write back into yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694656/jenkins-groovy-using-modified-data-from-readyaml-to-write-back-into-yml-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/)

```groovy
def editYaml(path, Closure cl) {
  def yaml = readYaml file: path
  cl.call(yaml)
  writeYaml file: path, data: yaml, overwrite: true
}

dir('test/ex/ex1') {
  editYaml('test.yaml') { yaml ->
    yaml.yyy.branch = "dev"
  }
}
```